# Надо исправить орфографические ошибки

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне надо чтобы кто то исправил здесь ошибки.Я не руский и не могу.Я знаю что здесь дают вопросы по программированию.Если не вы не можете то тогда скажите на какой сайт можно задать такой вопрос.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/ для русскоязычных пользователей. https://russian.stackexchange.com/ для иностранцев.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что.